# Dynamically select the value of a select item javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a select list of options, and when the user selects one of those options, I want to dynamically select the same option on another similar select list on the page.

So these are the two lists:

```
<select id='b_orientation'><option>Horizontal</option><option>Vertical</option></select>

<select id='orientation'><option>Horizontal</option><option>Vertical</option></select>
```

Now after the user changes `b_orientation`, I want `orientation` to mirror the change. So this is the relevant line of code for that:

```
$('#orientation').val($('#b_orientation'));
```

but it doesn't make a difference to `orientation`. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to mention `val()`

As of now you are adding `element` not  `element's value`.

Change your line to

```
$('#orientation').val($('#b_orientation').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value like this - `$('#b_orientation').val()`

```
$('#orientation').val($('#b_orientation').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

## **jQuery**

```
$('#orientation').val($('#b_orientation').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#b_orientation').change(function(){
    $('#orientation').val(this.value);
});
```